# How can I manage different weapons in manager script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making my rpg game in unity. As I need a lot of different weapons, I tried to make a script for each weapons. Then instead of enacting the Attack function in each weapon's object, I wanted to controll them in other class such as WeaponManager for some reason.
However, I got no idea how to manage variety of classes. It doesn't seem efficient to write all the codes for each classes, such as

```
if((gameObject).name=="Wand")
    gameObject.Getcomponent<Wand>().Attack();
else if((gameObject).name=="Sword")
    gameObject.Getcomponent<Sword>().Attack();
```

... and so on.

In other way, I also thought of SendMessage function, but it doesn't seem like efficient as well.

I'm wodering how can I solve this problem. Which method can I use?

Comment: Thats why they invented either inheritance or interfaces - whichrever you feel applies better

Comment: I think it's time to start using C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classical example use case for **object oriented programming**:

#### [Inheritance!](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/inheritance)

Use a shared **parent class** both inherit from and either implement the method [`virtual`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/virtual) with a shared **default** behavior the inheriting classes **can** overwrite/extend or make it [`abstract`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/abstract) so inheriting classes **have to** implement it.

```c#
public abstract class Weapon : MonoBehaviour 
{ 
    public abstract void Attack(); 

    // alternatively implement some default behavior
    // in this case the child classes can but don't have to override this
    //public virtual void Attack()
    //{
    //    Debug.Log("Harr Harr .. but I'll do nothing else!", this);
    //}
}
```

and then

```c#
public class Wand : Weapon 
{ 
    public override void Attack()
    { 
        ... 
    } 
}
```

and

```c#
public class Sword : Weapon 
{ 
    public override void Attack()
    { 
        ... 
    } 
}
```

---

then simply go

```c#
gameObject.GetComponent<Weapon>().Attack();
```

Comment: Oh, I haven't knew that I can call child class component by calling parent abstract class... Thank you for your kind answer! Now I get the solution.

Comment: Yes ofcourse you can ;) This is how for example Unity often uses only `Renderer` or `Collider` which basically means "Get me any renderer" which can be `MeshRenderer`, `SpriteRenderer`, `SkinnedMeshRenderer` .....